Extract Parameter types of interface call signatures
How can I define a type in typescript so that I can e.g. all the first parameter types of a function type:
interface Foo {
    (str: 'apple'|'banana'): void;
    (str: 'hat'): void;
    (x: number): void;
}

type ExtractAllParameters<T> = T extends (str: infer P ,...args: any) => any
    ? P : never;

so I would like to have ExtractAllParameters<Foo> get resolved to something like:
'apple'|'banana'|'hat'|number
but I only get number (since it's the last call signature from the interface)

You can’t do this in a scalable way (overloads can’t easily be manipulated in the type system); why do you have three different void-returning call signatures instead of one?
